# Explain the phrase "allowing what is"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Today I read from a book the phrase “meditation is *allowing what is*”. Can anyone explain what this phrase means in other words?

Context:

> So let’s keep it simple. Our definition of meditation: Meditation is allowing what is.

Comment: I think it means *"let whatever is be".* Something like *"que será, será"*, but in the present tense.

Comment: This is religion and the point is that you have to make up the meaning yourself. Correctly. Without any other context. You're **supposed** to be puzzled.

Comment: The meditation context makes the meaning plain. This is analogous to reading a Christian apologetic and wondering what "convicted by the spirit" means in context. If you are unfamiliar with Christian apologetics, it might make no sense, but the meaning in context is plain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Allowing what is” describes the mental attitude which the meditator takes during practice. It means *accepting reality* (what is), with an attitude of *giving consent to* or *accepting without opposing* (allowing).

One takes this attitude towards the focus of meditation: letting the breath, or footsteps, or chant take place without judgment or opposition. And, when internal thoughts and feelings surface, or when external sounds or movements intrude, one avoids being caught up either by such things or by one’s reaction to them. One allows awareness of any thing to simply occur and then to abate.

**References**
http://onelook.com/?w=allowing
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meditation

Answer (score 0):

The phrase seems to suggest this [meaning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/allow) of *allow*

> to admit; acknowledge; concede: *I had to allow that he was right.*

It feels like a type of surrender to existence.

Answer (score 0):

"Allowing what is" may be summed up by the lines of the poem/song:

*Que será, será

Whatever will be, will be.*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @BrianHooper Sorry - I thought the answer was self-explanatory - and the second line had come to me *before* I had read PeterShor's comment, but that did usefully provide the first line.